# How can I connect from unix terminal to a Microsoft SQL Server database? I have to connect on a SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql, linux, sql-server-2008

I have to connect on a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database from a linux server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Java on your linux machine, you can download some 
JDBC client which is 100% java and use it to connect to MS SQL Server.

You may e.g. look here for some more details.

http://java-source.net/open-source/sql-clients

But I doubt you can do it with a native tool, this is pretty obvious.
These tools will be probably limited compared to some native tool
but as there's no such tool, I guess they might be suitable and 
enough to do your job.